# Creating a list with words counted from multiple .docx files

Tags: python, list, docx

I'm trying to do a project where I automate my invoices for translation jobs. Basically the script reads multiple .docx files in a folder, counts words for every separate file, then writes those filenames and the corresponding word counts into Excel file.

I've created a word counter script, but can't figure out how to add the counted words to a list to later use this list to extract values from it for my Excel file, and create an invoice.

Here is my code:

```
import docx
import os
import re
from docx import Document

#Folder to work with    
folder = r'D:/Tulk_1'
files = os.listdir(folder)

#List with the names of files and word counts for each file
list_files = []
list_words = []

for file in files:
    #Getting the absolute location
    location = folder + '/' + file
    #Adding filenames to the list
    list_files.append(file)
    #Word counter
    document = docx.Document(location)
    newparatextlist = []
    for paratext in document.paragraphs:
        newparatextlist.append(paratext.text)
    #Printing file names
    print(file)
    #Printing word counts for each file
    print(len(re.findall(r'\w+', '\n'.join(newparatextlist))))
```

Output:

```
cold calls.docx
2950
Kristības.docx
1068
Tulkojums starpniecības līgums.docx
946
Tulkojums_PL_ULIHA_39_41_4 (1).docx
788
```

Unfortunately I copied the counter part from the web and the last line is too complicated for me:

```
print(len(re.findall(r'\w+', '\n'.join(newparatextlist))))
```

So I don't know how to extract the results out of it into a list.

When I try to store the last line into a variable like this:

```
x = len(re.findall(r'\w+', '\n'.join(newparatextlist)))
```

The output is only word count for one of the files:

```
cold calls.docx
Kristības.docx
Tulkojums starpniecības līgums.docx
Tulkojums_PL_ULIHA_39_41_4 (1).docx
788
```

Maybe you could help me to break the last line into smaller steps? Or perhaps there are easier solutions to my task?

EDIT:

The desired output for the:

```
print(list_words)
```

should be:

```
[2950, 1068, 946, 788]
```

Similar as it already is for file names:

```
print(list_files)
```

output:

```
['cold calls.docx', 'Kristības.docx', 'Tulkojums starpniecības līgums.docx', 'Tulkojums_PL_ULIHA_39_41_4 (1).docx']
```

Comment: Subdividing the last line shouldn't be necessary. Edit the question to show the desired output. Or explain how the resulting list should be structured (e. g. list of tuples with filename and word count?)?

Comment: Instead of or additionally to "print(file)" just append (using the "append" method) "file" to "list_files" list. Similarly append "len(re.findall(...))" to "list_words".